# How to connect two machines, both behind NAT?

Tags: nat

I have two machines, both behind a NAT-ting router, resulting that they can not exchange packets directly.

However, I believe such a thing would be still possible over some external help, if the NAT-ting firewalls are not very uncooperative cooperative and the protocol is stateless (probably UDP).

My idea would be this:

```
Machine1 -- Router1 <--> Router2 -- Machine2
```

My idea is that Machine1:30000 sends an UDP packet to Router2:30000. Thus, both the source and the target ports are 30000 (I chosen this number randomly).

Of course, Router2 won't transfer it, because its connection tracking does not know it.

*However, things are much better if also a reverse UDP packet, Machine2:30000 -> Router1:30000 is sent at the same time!*

Then, both router will think, the incoming packet is an answer to the outgoing UDP packet.

Of course, routers must allow UDP<sup>1</sup> and they should not alter the source port of new outgoing connections.

Does it exist? Is there maybe a command line tool for that?

<sup>1</sup><sub>I have already seen s..uboptimal [ISP](https://m-net.de) where UDP was just disabled without explanation and their customer support did not want to understand, what I am talking about. Not even their L2 support.</sub>

Comment: I have also a very primitive and very trivial idea - just setting up OpenVPN over UDP, with the same source and target ports...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal#Techniques

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make life easy for yourself, I'd recommend checking out [Tailscale](https://www.tailscale.com/). Tailscale allows you to punch through basically anything. The nice thing about it is that it even allows you to access devices on your physical subnet that don't allow you to install software on them - such as printers etc. - too.

**EDIT:** I am *not* affiliated with Tailscale in any way; I'm just an end-user who finds the technology, and the solution itself, brilliant. It is free to install on up to 100 devices.

Here's a couple of points, for those who are curious:

- **Zero Configuration Networking**
- **Secure Connections:** it uses WireGuard.
- **Easy to scale**
- **Cross-platform:** it supports Windows, macOS, Linux, iOS, and Android (and probably more).
- **It automatically creates a peer-to-peer mesh network**
- **Access Control (ACL):** Offers fine-grained access controls, allowing you to manage who has access to what within the network.
- It's designed to be **lightweight**, which makes it suitable for use even on less powerful hardware (I run it on my old RasPI).
- **Subnet Routing:** it allows subnet routing, enabling devices on your network to access other devices in your local subnet (like printers) that can't have Tailscale installed. This feature extends the utility of Tailscale to virtually all devices on your network.
- **No Need for Public IP Addresses:** it eliminates the need for public IP addresses for each device.
- **End-to-End Encryption**
- **NAT Traversal:** it effectively handles NAT traversal, allowing devices behind NAT, CGNAT etc. to communicate with each other seamlessly.
- ... and a lot more.

There's plenty documentation around for those curious. I would encourage whoever reads this post to not take my word for it and, instead, read about it themselves.

Comment: What is that? I want NAT punching, not yet another VPN!

Comment: Oh I understand. You are spamming us with your own, paid, VPN solution, making this post not-answer AND spam. I reported your as spam.

Comment: @peterh There are [several other users discussing tailscale](https://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=tailscale+is%3AA), at least one of whom said there was a free version. Let's be careful with spam flags until the situation is clearer.  telometto: could you please [edit] your post to add (or disclaim) any affiliation you have with the Tailscale product? Thank you!

Comment: @JeffSchaller to be honest, I'm not affiliated with Tailscale in any way. I'm just an end user who really enjoys it. I'm not at home right now, but I can edit the post to give a more comprehensive answer when I do get home.

Comment: @peterh I wasn't spamming; I saw your own comment under your op and thought that since it doesn't look like OpenVPN is off the table, that I'd suggest Tailscale. It's completely free for up to 100 devices and it sets up a mesh network - using WireGuard - *for* you, and only allows devices that you whitelist to access said network/devices. That being said, I'm not here to argue your technological choices with you; you do you.